# golang check if cli integer flag exists

Tags: go, flags

I'm able to see if a flag exists when its a bool. I'm trying to figure out how to see if a flag exits if its integer, if it does exist use the value if not ignore.

For example, the code below does something if either Bool flags are used. BUT I want to set a flag for `-month` ie `go run appname.go -month=01` should then save the value of 01 but if `-month` is not used then it should be ignored like a bool flag. In the code below I got around this by making a default value of 0 so if no `-month` flag is used the value is 0. Is there a better way to do this?

```
package main

import (
    "flag"
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    //Adding flags
    useCron := flag.Bool("cron", false, "-cron, uses cron flags and defaults to true")
    useNow := flag.Bool("now", false, "-now, uses cron flags and defaults to true")
    useMonth := flag.Int("month", 0, "-month, specify a month")
    flag.Parse()

    //If -cron flag is used
    if *useCron {
        fmt.Printf("Cron set using cron run as date")
        return
    } else if *useNow {
        fmt.Printf("Use Current date")
        return
    }

    if *useMonth != 0 {
        fmt.Printf("month %v\n", *useMonth)
    }
}
```

Comment: there is *no* other way to use `flag`.  There's no way to create a flag without a default value.  You can't really support `0` as a valid month along with 1 anyway, without further disambiguation.  So it seems that a default value of `0` is a good indicator that month was not set.  In your documentation you can inlude a note, `(0 to disable)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the documentation and example for the [`flag.Value`](https://pkg.go.dev/flag#Value) interface :

You may define a custom type, which implements `flag.Value`, for example :

```
type CliInt struct {
    IsSet bool
    Val   int
}

func (i *CliInt) String() string {
    if !i.IsSet {
        return "<not set>"
    }
    return strconv.Itoa(i.Val)
}

func (i *CliInt) Set(value string) error {
    v, err := strconv.Atoi(value)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    i.IsSet = true
    i.Val = v
    return nil
}
```

and then use `flag.Var()` to bind it :

```
    flag.Var(&i1, "i1", "1st int to parse")
    flag.Var(&i2, "i2", "2nd int to parse")
```

after calling `flag.Parse()`, you may check the `.IsSet` flag to see if that flag was set.

[playground](https://go.dev/play/p/WqbjI4Hm7ny)

---

Another way is to call [`flag.Visit()`](https://pkg.go.dev/flag#Visit) after calling `flag.Parse()` :

```
    var isSet1, isSet2 bool

    i1 := flag.Int("i1", 0, "1st int to parse")
    i2 := flag.Int("i2", 0, "2nd int to parse")

    flag.Parse([]string{"-i1=123"})

    // flag.Visit will only visit flags which have been explicitly set :
    flag.Visit(func(fl *flag.Flag) {
        if fl.Name == "i1" {
            isSet1 = true
        }
        if fl.Name == "i2" {
            isSet2 = true
        }
    })
```

[playground](https://go.dev/play/p/XJHlCkpUIuT)

Answer (score 0):

In the bool flag also you can't check if exist or not because you are checking the default `false` value. If you will change it to `true` you will always get it as exists.

```
useCron := flag.Bool("cron", true, "-cron, uses cron flags and defaults to true")
useNow := flag.Bool("now", true, "-now, uses cron flags and defaults to true")
```

The same goes for any other data type, we can only check the default values.

You can use `flag.NFlag()`.
This function returns a number of flags set by the CLI.
This option makes sense when all the options are required.

@LeGEC answer fulfills your requirement.